# Javascript gravity forms, reference field

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I need to add a js function into a gravity forms field. I want to take a result from an id=4 field, and add this number as input for a js function, then run the function:

```
var defaultRate = 1.7;
var halfRate = 1.65;

if (*field id=3* >= *field id=4* /2 ) {
  return halfRate;
} else { 
  return defaultRate;
},
```

and get the result as an output for my field. How do I refence them? Where do I paste the code? html field or custom js in settings?
I have seen this to use into custom js

```
<script>
gform.addFilter( 'gform_calculation_formula', function( formula, formulaField, formId, calcObj ) {
    if ( formId == '8' && formulaField.field_id == '13' ) {
        formula += '+5';
    }
    return formula;
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [Gravity Forms Advanced Calculations](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-advanced-calculations/).

```
if ( F3 >= F4 ):
    1.65
else:
    1.7
endif;
```

The F3 and F4 refer to field IDs 3 and 4 respectively. If you find it clarifies the formula further, you could include the full or partial merge tag:

`{:3}` and `{My Field:3}`

`{:4}` and `{My Other Field:4}`